# What is a 'life endeavour'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a general idea...like the main effort/goal in one's life but I may be mistaken.

I met it in this line:
"when your life endeavour evades your clever meddling"

Comment: Correctly, it is , **life's** endeavour, *note the genitive 's'*. -- OED: endeavour(n.) *1.a. The action of endeavouring; effort, or pains, directed to attain an object; a strenuous attempt or enterprise.* -- The words seem to be taken from the lyrics of a song: song lyrics are often unreliable as examples of good English.

Comment: @Greybeard Generally unreliable; however, this particular fragment is perfectly usable: "When your... meddling, pull your belt a little tighter and keep pedalling."